# Outputting manual JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am building some JSON myself like so:

```
 echo '{ "type": "root",';
 echo '"children" : [';
 echo '{';
 echo '"identifier": "Contractor",';
 echo '"title": "Contractor",';
 echo '"autoIdentifier": true,';
 echo '"options": [';
    foreach ($names as $n){
       echo '{';
       echo '"text": '.'"'.$n['name'].'",';
       echo '"identifier": '.'"'.$n['id'].'"';
       echo '},';
    }
 echo '],';
 echo '"title": "TEST",';
 echo '"description": ""';
 echo '}';
```

As you can see i am looping through some data to print into the JSON output. The problem i am having is the last echo within the loop. This is because it currently has a comma after the bracket.

However if it is the last element within my data loop, i want the comma to be removed so that it creates proper JSON.

How can i achieve this? With some kind of counter and then an if statement?

Comment: can u tel y you want to do it manually??

Comment: Do not echo everything. Just put all in a variable. After the loop use rtrim on the variable to remove the last comma and then echo the variable

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju many times I prefer not to ask... ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$names = array_map(function($name) {
    return '{ "text":"' . $name['name'] . '", "identifier":"' . $name['id'] . '" }';
}, $names);

echo '{ "type": "root",';
echo '"children" : [';
echo '{';
echo '"identifier": "Contractor",';
echo '"title": "Contractor",';
echo '"autoIdentifier": true,';
echo '"options": [';
echo implode(',', $names);
echo '],';
echo '"title": "TEST",';
echo '"description": ""';
echo '}';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd seriously prefer just using PHPs JSON encoding features, [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). For example, what if the `$n["name"]` had a quote in it? Your JSON would be invalid, but if you used `json_encode`, it'd take care of that.

```
$child = [
    "identifier"     => "Contractor",
    "autoIdentifier" => true,
    "options"        => [],
    "title"          => "TEST",
    "description"    => ""
];

foreach ($names as $n)
{
    $child["options"][] = [
        "text"       => $n["name"],
        "identifier" => $n["id"]
    ];
}

header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
echo json_encode( ["type" => "root", "children" => [$child]] );
```

Answer (score 0):

change your loop to:

```
$var = '';
foreach ($names as $n){
       $var .= '{';
       $var .= '"text": "'.$n['name'].'",';
       $var .= '"identifier": "'.$n['id'].'"';
       $var .= '} ,';
    }
$var = rtrim($var,",");
echo $var;
```

OR
change your code like this:

```
$var = '{ "type": "root","children" : [{"identifier": "Contractor","title": "Contractor","autoIdentifier": true,"options": [';
foreach ($names as $n){
    $var .= '{"text": "'.$n["name"].'","identifier": "'.$n["id"].'"} ,';
}
$var = rtrim($var,",");
$var =  '],"title": "TEST","description": ""}';
echo $var;
```

Comment: ``'.'`` could be removed

Comment: no, because echo is after loop, so '.' is to concatenate all records of loop